# error: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module

I am working on a linux kernel module.

A struct tcpsp_conn is defined in the header file as follows:

```
struct tcpsp_conn {
...
struct timer_list timer; /* exp. timer*/
...
};
```

Then I declare a pointer to the structure and try to assign the function:

```
struct tcpsp_conn *cp;
cp->timer.function = tcpsp_conn_expire;
```

tcpsp_conn_expire function is defined in the same way as in the struct timer_list of the kernel:

```
static void tcpsp_conn_expire(unsigned long data)
```

I don't understand why am I getting this error:
*error: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
  cp->timer.function = tcpsp_conn_expire;*

It doesn't look to have a problem with types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type of your `tcpsp_conn_expire` function **differs** from the type of `.function` field of the `timer_list` structure.

In the newest kernel (since 4.15) this function-field is declared with `struct timer_list *` argument instead of `unsigned long`, as follows:

```
struct timer_list {
    ...
    void            (*function)(struct timer_list *);
    ...
};
```

Having such argument, you may obtain the pointer to the `struct tcpsp_conn` structure, into which the timer is embedded, with macro `container_of`.

Comment: Yes, I just noticed that they differ. I checked a newer kernel than the current one I'm working in. My bad ;)